# React js dateFns problem on codesandbox 'format' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codesandbox

Error:

```
Cannot read property 'format' of undefined
```

Error in code:

```
<span>{dateFns.format(currentDate, dateFormat)}</span>
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-neumann-22dl1)

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import dateFns from "date-fns";
import "./Calendar.css";
const Calendar = () => {
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  const header = () => {
    const dateFormat = "MMMM YYYY";
    return (
      <div className="header row flex-middle">
        <div className="column col-start">
          <div className="icon" onClick={prevMonth}>
            chevron_left
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="column col-center">
          <span>{dateFns.format(currentDate, dateFormat)}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="column col-end">
          <div className="icon" onClick={nextMonth}>
            chevron_right
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
  const days = () => {
    const dateFormat = "ddd";
    const days = [];
    let startDate = dateFns.startOfWeek(currentDate);
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      days.push(
        <div className="column col-center" key={i}>
          {dateFns.format(dateFns.addDays(startDate, i), dateFormat)}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div className="days row">{days}</div>;
  };
  const cells = () => {
    const monthStart = dateFns.startOfMonth(currentDate);
    const monthEnd = dateFns.endOfMonth(monthStart);
    const startDate = dateFns.startOfWeek(monthStart);
    const endDate = dateFns.endOfWeek(monthEnd);
    const dateFormat = "D";
    const rows = [];
    let days = [];
    let day = startDate;
    let formattedDate = "";
    while (day <= endDate) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        formattedDate = dateFns.format(day, dateFormat);
        const cloneDay = day;
        days.push(
          <div
            className={`column cell ${
              !dateFns.isSameMonth(day, monthStart)
                ? "disabled"
                : dateFns.isSameDay(day, selectedDate)
                ? "selected"
                : ""
            }`}
            key={day}
            onClick={() => onDateClick(dateFns.parse(cloneDay))}
          >
            <span className="number">{formattedDate}</span>
            <span className="bg">{formattedDate}</span>
          </div>
        );
        day = dateFns.addDays(day, 1);
      }
      rows.push(
        <div className="row" key={day}>
          {" "}
          {days}{" "}
        </div>
      );
      days = [];
    }
    return <div className="body">{rows}</div>;
  };
  const nextMonth = () => {
    setCurrentDate(dateFns.addMonths(currentDate, 1));
  };
  const prevMonth = () => {
    setCurrentDate(dateFns.subMonths(currentDate, 1));
  };
  const onDateClick = day => {
    setSelectedDate(day);
  };
  return (
    <div className="calendar">
      <div>{header()}</div>
      <div>{days()}</div>
      <div>{cells()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Calendar;
```

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 5):

you have to import **Format** from date-fns/esm.
like this:

```
import {format} from "date-fns/esm"
```

Comment: I think it should be`import {format} from "date-fns"`

Comment: In previous versions of date-fns we can import like that as you shared but in new version if we are using Ecmascript 6 we have to import it from ESM directory.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is in **import**

In this case you'll need to

1. remove **`import dateFns from "date-fns";`**
2. Then remove `dateFns` from all the methods you'll need to import :

   {dateFns.format(currentDate, dateFormat)}

Correct version:

```
 {format(currentDate, dateFormat)}
```

Same should be done for

```
let startDate = dateFns.startOfWeek(currentDate);
```

Correct version: `let startDate = startOfWeek(currentDate);` 
etc. with the rest of the methods.

3. Import all the methods are used in your case from "date-fns":

   import {
       format,
       startOfWeek,
       addDays,
       startOfMonth,
       endOfMonth,
       endOfWeek,
       isSameMonth,
       isSameDay,
       parse,
       subMonths,
       addMonths
   } from "date-fns";

After those steps done it will work!